# Is $C=\left\{ \left(x,y,z\right)^{T}\mid xyz\geq1,\sqrt{xy}\geq z,x>0,y>0,z>0\right\} $ is a convex set?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I want to ask if $$C=\left\{ \left(x,y,z\right)^{T}\mid xyz\geq1,\sqrt{xy}\geq z,x>0,y>0,z>0\right\} $$ is a convex set. 
I know that:

- $\forall a\in\left\{ x,y,z\right\} :\left\{ \left(x,y,z\right)^{T}\mid a>0\right\} $ is a half space and therefore a convex set

I want to use a theorem that said that the intersection of convex sets is a convex set,but I don't really whether or not the sets $$\left\{ \left(x,y,z\right)^{T}\mid xyz\geq1\right\} ,\left\{ \left(x,y,z\right)^{T}\mid\sqrt{xy}\geq z\right\} $$ are convex at all.
maybe the theorem about intersection is not the best idea to solve this one.

I also tired to proof that $C$ is convex according to the definition of convex sets but it became complicated.

thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It is a convex set.

Let $(x_1, y_1, z_1)\in C$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2) \in C$. Let $0\le t \le 1$.
We have to prove that $(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2, \ ty_1 + (1-t)y_2, \ tz_1 + (1-t)z_2) \in C$.

First, by Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{align}
\sqrt{[tx_1 + (1-t)x_2][ty_1 + (1-t)y_2]} &\ge t\sqrt{x_1y_1} + (1-t)\sqrt{x_2y_2}\\
 &\ge tz_1 + (1-t)z_2
\end{align}
since $\sqrt{x_1y_1}\ge z_1$ and $\sqrt{x_2y_2} \ge z_2$.

Second, by Holder inequality, we have
\begin{align}
&[tx_1 + (1-t)x_2]\, [ty_1 + (1-t)y_2] \, [ tz_1 + (1-t)z_2]\\
\ge\ & (t\sqrt[3]{x_1y_1z_1} + (1-t)\sqrt[3]{x_2y_2z_2})^3 \\
\ge\ & (t + 1-t)^3 \\
=\ & 1
\end{align}
since $x_1y_1z_1 \ge 1$ and $x_2y_2z_2 \ge 1$.
**Another way**:
Note that $f(x, y, z) = \sqrt[3]{xyz}$ is concave on $\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: \ x > 0, y > 0, z > 0\}$. See [[How can it be proved that the geometric mean function is concave?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452722/how-can-it-be-proved-that-the-geometric-mean-function-is-concave])
Thus, we have 
\begin{align}
&f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2, \ ty_1 + (1-t)y_2, \ tz_1 + (1-t)z_2)\\
\ge\ & tf(x_1, y_1, z_1) + (1-t)f(x_2, y_2, z_2)\\
\ge\ & 1.
\end{align}

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

**Another solution**:

*Fact 1*: Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers. Denote $x = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$. Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathrm{R}^n$ be a convex set.  Suppose $f_k(x)$, $k=1, 2, \cdots, m$ are convex functions on $\Omega$.
Then, $S = \{x\in \Omega: \ f_k(x) \le 0, \ k= 1, 2, \cdots, m\}$ is convex.

[*Proof of Fact 1*: Let $u\in S$ and $v\in S$. Let $0 \le t \le 1$.
For $k=1, 2, \cdots, m$, we have $f_k(tu+(1-t)v) \le tf_k(u) + (1-t)f_k(v) \le 0$.
Thus, $tu + (1-t)v \in S$.
We are done.]

Now, for our problem,
since $f_1(x, y, z) = -\sqrt[3]{xyz} + 1$ and $f_2(x, y, z) = -\sqrt{xy} + z$ are convex functions on
$\{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : \ x > 0, y > 0, z > 0\}$, by Fact 1, 
$\{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: \ -\sqrt[3]{xyz} + 1\le 0, \ -\sqrt{xy} + z \le 0, \ x > 0, \ y > 0, \ z > 0\}$ is convex. We are done.

Comment: What did you plug into Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: @OmerBen $(a_1 + a_2)(b_1 + b_2) \ge (\sqrt{a_1b_1} + \sqrt{a_2b_2})^2$, $a_1 = tx_1, a_2 = (1-t)x_2, b_1 = ty_1, b_2 = (1-t)y_2$.

Comment: Is there any other easier way to do it? I didn't learn about Holder inequality.Thanks!

Comment: @OmerBen  No problem. Actually, Holder inequality is powerful. It might be a good idea to know it. FYI. https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/H%C3%B6lder%27s_Inequality

Comment: @OmerBen  Another way is to use $f(x, y, z) = \sqrt[3]{xyz}$ is concave on $\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: \ x > 0, y > 0, z > 0\}$.

Comment: I show that $f\left(x,y,z\right)=-\sqrt[3]{xyz}$ is convex and then used on the theorem that the sublevel set of $f$ is convex for $t=0$ ,$\Rightarrow$ the set $\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & z\end{array}\right)^{T}\mid\sqrt{xyz}\geq1\right\} $ is convex.
but what about the set $\sqrt{xy}\geq z$ ? I can show that for each $t \in \mathbb{R}$ $\sqrt{xy}\geq t$ is convex set but there is no theorem (that I know) about union of convex set.
In short :how can I prove that $$\left\{ \sqrt{xy}\geq z\mid\left(x,y,z\right)\in\mathbb{R}_{++}^{3},,\sqrt{xyz}\geq1\right\} $$ is convex?
thanks

Comment: @OmerBen  I updated my answer, please take a look if it is helpful.