# Concavity of function with four variables

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, convex-analysis, inequality

Can we use concavity to prove the following statement

$$f(\theta a + (1-\theta)c, \theta b + (1-\theta)d) \geq \theta f(a, b) + (1-\theta) f(c, d)$$
The $f(x, y)$ can be defined as $f(x, y) = x^{1\over 2}y^{1\over 2}$. Or use other method to prove this. Thanks!

Comment: Geometric mean is concave on $(0,\infty)^n$, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452722/how-can-it-be-proved-that-the-geometric-mean-function-is-concave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality you have written is true for concave functions (it is basically Jensen's inequality for -f). The function is twice differentiable on $(0,\infty)^2$, so we may use its Hessian matrix. A twice-differentiable function is concave if and only if its Hessian matrix is negative-semidefinite (has all eigenvalues negative or zero).

\begin{align}
H &= \begin{pmatrix}-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{4x^\frac{3}{2}} & \frac{1}{4\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}}\\ \frac{1}{4\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}}& -\frac{\sqrt{x}}{4y^\frac{3}{2}}\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \frac{1}{4\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}}\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{y}{x} & 1\\ 1& -\frac{x}{y}\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
 We can compute the eigenvalues of the second matrix as solutions of
\begin{align}
\left(\lambda + \frac{y}{x}\right)\left(\lambda + \frac{x}{y}\right) -1 = 0
\end{align}
this is pretty easy to solve with the quadratic formula
\begin{align}
0&=\lambda^2 + \lambda\left(\frac{y}{x} + \frac{x}{y}\right) + 1 -1\\
\lambda_\pm &= -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y}{x} + \frac{x}{y}\right)\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\left(\frac{y}{x} + \frac{x}{y}\right)^2 }\\
\implies \lambda_+ &= 0\\
\lambda_- &= -\frac{y}{x} - \frac{x}{y}.
\end{align}

So one eigenvalue is negative and the other is zero, so the matrix is negative-semidefinite and $f$ is concave.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there anything wrong with the second line of the Hessian matrix? In the matrix, it should be -y/x and -x/y.

Comment: @Wesley oops, yeah - I'll fix it now

Comment: The quadratic formula should be 0= lambda^2 + lambda({y/x+ x/y}) + 1 - 1, right?

Comment: @Wesley Yeah, I'm an idiot...sorry for all the errors

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you further show me how to apply Jansen's inequality with multivariate variables, to get the desired result?