# How to prove the geometric mean is concave?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

How to prove the geometric mean is concave?

The geometric mean is $()=(\prod_{i=1}^nx_i)^{1/}$ is concave on dom =ℝ++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are going to use the AM-GM inequality: $$\frac{a_1 + a_2+\cdots +a_n}{n} \ge (a_1a_2\ldots a_n)^{1/n}.$$

Applying AM-GM for $a_i = \frac{x_i}{\lambda x_i + (1 - \lambda)y_i}$, then for $a_i = \frac{y_i}{\lambda x_i + (1 - \lambda)y_i}$, we get:

\begin{align}
\frac{f(x)}{f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y)} = \left(\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{\lambda x_i + (1 - \lambda)y_i} \right)^{1/n} &\le \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{\lambda x_i + (1 - \lambda)y_i} \right),\\
\frac{f(y)}{f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y)} =\left(\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{y_i}{\lambda x_i + (1 - \lambda)y_i} \right)^{1/n} &\le \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{y_i}{\lambda x_i + (1 - \lambda)y_i} \right).
\end{align}
Multiply the first inequality by $\lambda$, and the second by $(1 - \lambda)$, then sum up the two we get
\begin{equation}
\frac{\lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda)f(y)}{f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y)} \le 1.
\end{equation}
We are done.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe overkill but you could use [Mahler's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahler%27s_inequality) to show this. Indeed,

$$
f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y) =
\prod_{i=1}^n (\lambda x_i + (1 - \lambda)y_i)^{1/n}
\geq \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda^{1/n} x_i^{1/n} + \prod_{i=1}^n (1 - \lambda)^{1/n} y_i^{1/n} \\
= (\lambda^{1/n})^{n} \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{1/n} + \left((1 - \lambda)^{1/n}\right)^n
\prod_{i=1}^n y_i^{1/n} = \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda) f(y).
$$

Comment: For the third part it should be $(1 - \lambda)^{1/n} y_i^{1/n}$ rather than  $(1 - \lambda)^{1/n} y_i^n$

Comment: @Frank good catch! Thanks.

Comment: (+1) Not really overkill. f10w's answer essentially proves Mahler's inequality, so yours is essentially as simple.